# .each is executing block on empty array

Tags: ruby

I've always known that:

```
a = []

a.each do |x|
  puts "I'm still being executed"
end
```

will output just nothing until the array is an empty array. It so behaves in the console too. But in my application my code is still executing the block on an empty array and I've been unable to debug it. Is there something I am missing?

**EDIT:**
Here's the original code:

```
<% @idea.comments.each do |c| %>
  <div class="left_box gray">
    <%= c.body %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

whereas @idea `has_many` comments.

Comment: (the array is probably not empty)

Comment: @AJcodez well it appears you are right. Calling `@idea.comments.inspect` within the application shows that it still returns a comment object, although blank with only keys and no values. I never knew of this behavior. Besides, in the console `@idea.comments.inspect` returns an empty array. Why this difference?

Comment: I found the bug. `@idea.comments.new` was being called in one of the includes which was making the array non-empty.

Comment: Oooh was just gonna ask if you were calling new somewhere. Glad its worked out

Answer (score 3):

It is impossible. Something wrong in your code. See your code carefully.

Comment: maybe some monkeypatching going on behind the scenes?